# Разграничение модулей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть два разных пакета (скаченные с pypi), которые вызываются одним и тем же именем (прим.) `import stack`. Можно ли их как-нибудь разграничить/переименовать, чтобы были оба пакета без потери их функциональности? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import path1.stack as stack_1
import path_2.stack as stack_2
```

---

**Update**

> Не получилось, определяется только один пакет

Я не понимаю, почему у вас определяется только один пакет.

**main.py**

```
import Test.stack as stack_1

import Test.pro.stack as stack_2
```

**Test/stack.py**

```
print("stack_1")
```

**Test/pro/stack.py**

```
print("stack_2")
```

---

**Output:**

```
stack_1
stack_2
```

Comment: Не получилось, определяется только один пакет

Comment: @Алексей  я добавил приме, в котором видно что все получается.

Comment: @S.Nick Попробуйте установить `python-benedict` и `benedict`. А потом достучаться до `benedict` каждого пакета по-отдельности. Думаю, у ТСа проблема в этом. @Алексей Вам бы следовало привести примеры пакетов, для которых пытаетесь это сделать.